# Image Stamper With Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Trying to make a date stamping image program. Don't know why I am getting a file not found error, the program is showing its finding the imagetostamp.jpg file, by pulling the file name in the error

```
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

dir_list = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\...\IMAGESTAMPFOLDER')

# Loop over all files in the working directory.
for filename in dir_list:
    im = Image.open(filename)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    fontsFolder = 'C:\Windows\Fonts' # e.g. ‘/Library/Fonts'
    arialFont = ImageFont.truetype(os.path.join(fontsFolder, 'arial.ttf'), 32)
    draw.text((100,150), '08/14/2020', fill='red', font=arialFont)
    im.save('text.png')
```

Error

```
im = Image.open(filename)
File "C:\Users\...\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2878, in open
fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'imagetostamp.jpg'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code fixed the problem

```
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

files = os.listdir(r'C:\Users...\Desktop\IMAGESTAMPFOLDER')

# Loop over all files in the working directory.
for file in files:
    im = Image.open(os.path.join(r'C:\Users...\Desktop\IMAGESTAMPFOLDER', file))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    fontsFolder = 'C:\Windows\Fonts' # e.g. ‘/Library/Fonts'
    arialFont = ImageFont.truetype(os.path.join(fontsFolder, 'arial.ttf'), 32)
    draw.text((100,150), '08/14/2020', fill='red', font=arialFont)
    im.save('text.png')
```